# iOS-Objective-C: On Pushing View Controller, Tabbar not displaying (Its getting hide)

Tags: ios, objective-c, navigationbar, tabbar

**My storyboard is as below:**
[image]

**My appdelegate:**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UITabBarController *tabBarController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"rootTabBarVC"];
    self.window.rootViewController = tabBarController;
    return YES;
}
```

**I have side menu and from that I am pushing VC1 as follows:**

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
VC1 *contr = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"VC1"];
[self.navCon pushViewController:contr animated:YES];
```

**My problem is: VC1 is pushing but tabbar gets hide. So, anyone can please help me to show tabbar on pushing VC?**

Comment: Try making the initial navigation controller of which the tabBar is the root as window's rootviewController

Comment: Push Tabbarcontroller with selected index of VC1

Comment: You are setting the Root View Controller of your Nav Controller to a TabBarController... *any* view you then Push onto the Nav Controller stack will "push out" your TabBarController. Surely, that's not what you want, is it?

Answer (score 0):

Probably, your view controller's `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` is set to `true`. You can also check that in the storyboard like in the screen shot.[image]

Comment: You have to push your view controller, on the navigation controller of your current tab bar. Which means, that each tab bar view controller has to be embedded within a navigation controller. But I guess that's not a good approach too. So to sum up: if you push your view controller, on tab bar's navigation controller, you won't be able to retain the tab bar visible.

Comment: I have embeded navigation for VC but, that one also not working for me.

Comment: Are you still pushing like `[self.navCon pushViewController:contr animated:YES];` ? What is your updated code

Comment: But you actually have to push on one of the tab bar items navigation controller. Something like: [self.tabbarcontorller.viewcontrollers.first.navigationController push]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146539/discussion-between-oleg-danu-and-sagar-sukode).

Answer (score 0):

Try this one , in your **AppDelegate.h** file set:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UITabBarController *tabBarCon;
```

Then in your **AppDelegate.m** file in :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *viewController =  [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"InitialNavCon"];
    self.window.rootViewController = viewController; 
}
```

Lastly when you are navigating from your side menu, you can to this put tab bar controller delegate **UITabBarControllerDelegate** in interface, then declare appdelegate as:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) AppDelegate *appDelegate; 
// for NAVIGATION use this :
  self.appDelegate.tabBarCon = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainTabBarController"]; // Set your TABBAR CONTROLLER TO "MainTabBarController"
  [[UITabBar appearance] setItemWidth:self.appDelegate.window.frame.size.width/4.0];
  self.appDelegate.tabBarCon.delegate=self;
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.appDelegate.tabBarCon animated:YES]; // then navigate
```

Set your initial navigation controller with essentials like this : 
[image]

Your connection to the Tab bar should be like this  with a navigation controller to each tabVC: [image]